# Is there a reference definition of higher-order logic as in HOL, Isabelle, etc?

Tags: logic, isabelle

I am reading ["Concrete semantics with Isabelle/HOL"](http://www.concrete-semantics.org) and I am getting very intrigued by higher-order logic. I know ordinary first-order logic and some modal logic but I have little if none previous exposure to higher-order logic and its metatheory, so I would like to fill the gap. I read that HOL is essentially Church's Theory of simple types and Pure is an intuitionistic variant of the former. The problem is the "essentially" word: How do the Isabelle/HOL and Isabelle/Pure theories differ from, e.g., [Andrews' textbook](http://gtps.math.cmu.edu/tttp.html)? Is there a textbook introduction to the kind of higher-order logic used in Isabelle/HOL and Isabelle/Pure, with some discussion of their metatheoretical properties?

Answer (score 1):

A lot can be said about HOL and its many variants and dialects.  It is a recurrent topic on the mailing lists of [Isabelle](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/listinfo/cl-isabelle-users) and the other [HOL](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/hol-info) systems.  For example, here is a relevent thread from Jan/Feb 2013 on `isabelle-users`: [Where to learn about HOL vs FOL?](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2013-January/msg00231.html) with a few more references to relavant literature.

There is also a little bit about the logic of Isabelle/Pure (which is minimal HOL) in the [Isabelle/Isar Implementation](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2014/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/implementation.pdf) manual, section ***2 Primitive logic***.